# Duplicate Primary Key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

first time using stack. I'm working through a MySql project and keep running into an error stating there is a duplicate entry for key "primary". I have redone the database about 3 times (since its small) and continue to run into the same problem. Attached is the ERD as well as my code to create the tables and their keys. Any ideas on how this could be resolved? I'm more so trying to understand why this even happened in the first place. [ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCLgX.jpg)
Code:

```
//Create Customers Table

CREATE TABLE Customers (
CustomerID int,
FirstName VARCHAR(25),
LastName VARCHAR(25),
Street VARCHAR(50),
City VARCHAR(50),
State VARCHAR(25),
ZipCode int,
Telephone VARCHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID)
);

//Create Orders Table

CREATE TABLE Orders (
OrderID int,
CustomerID int, 
SKU VARCHAR(20),
Description VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (OrderID)
);

//Create RMA Table

CREATE TABLE RMA (
Reason VARCHAR(25),
RMAID int,
OrderID int,
Status VARCHAR(50),
Step VARCHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY (RMAID)
);


ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Collaborator(CustomerID);

ALTER TABLE RMA
ADD FOREIGN KEY(OrderID) REFERENCES Orders(OrderID);

//LOAD DATA 

LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/codio/workspace/customers.csv'
INTO TABLE Collaborator
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/codio/workspace/orders.csv'
INTO TABLE Orders
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/codio/workspace/rma.csv'
INTO TABLE RMA
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Comment: duplicate primary key error coming for which table? Please check your customers.csv, orders.csv and rma.csv for any duplicate values for columns "CustomerID", "OrderID" & "RMAID" respectively.

Comment: *`ALTER TABLE Orders ADD FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Collaborator(CustomerID);`* - I do not see `Collaborator` table in your dump. *error stating there is a duplicate entry for key "primary".* - this error occures on a stage of loading data (`LOAD DATA INFILE`) and means there are some problems in some source CSV file.

Comment: UPDATE: Somehow, or someway all of the data loaded into it randomly. I believe this may have been an ide error (Codio). I'll remove post, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Purely an IDE problem, The tables, keys and load data statements work as desired. Thank You !

Comment: It might have happened because it loaded the data a second time. Either way. glad it worked for you and welcome to SO.